# Tappable Link in UITextView would navigate to another controller

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextview

I am working to navigate screen by clicking on the url link in textview.

**This is my code**

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        print("click event url:", URL)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blogsViewController") as! BlogsViewController
        vc.url = URL.absoluteString
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        return true
    }
}
```

But this link open to safari browser rather to navigate to specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open another view controller instead of browser you should only return false in delegate method.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
   func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

       print("click event url:", URL)
       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blogsViewController") as! BlogsViewController
       vc.url = URL.absoluteString
       navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       return false //instead of true
   }
}
```

This should be enough to your purpose.